# Ruby Heroku app "Rake Aborted" and "Precompiling assets failed" so "Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby App"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I've never used Ruby and an entire day of Googling has left me still stuck!  An outsourced developer just supplied this code with the instructions to deploy on Heroku -- then went completely silent.

I'm trying to deploy to Heroku via the Github repository.  Here's what seems to be the potentially relevant portions of the build output.

**Please let me know if any other information is needed (for instance, code from files) and I'll post it right away.**

Thank you a ton for helping out a flailing non-coder.

Bundle Install:

```
Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
....
Your bundle is complete!
   Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
   It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Post-install message from rdoc:
   Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
   <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
   = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
   = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
   >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
   Post-install message from rufus-scheduler:
   ***
   Thanks for installing rufus-scheduler 3.0.9
   It might not be 100% compatible with rufus-scheduler 2.x.
   If you encounter issues with this new rufus-scheduler, especially
   if your app worked fine with previous versions of it, you can
   A) Forget it and peg your Gemfile to rufus-scheduler 2.0.24
   and / or
   B) Take some time to carefully report the issue at
   https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues
   For general help about rufus-scheduler, ask via:
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=rufus-scheduler+ruby
   Cheers.
```

Rake aborted:

```
   Bundle completed (103.44s)
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/build_40e2be2d308d4bfdb76752ea1cf61c82/champ-nr-1dcd52f65ba486073cef2e1c8447c02c71332fec/config/sidekiq.yml
```

Closing failure comments:

```
!     Precompiling assets failed.
!

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Answer (score 0):

It is saying you dont have `config/sidekiq.yml`, I assume that is the actual issue. You can add that file and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks!  So...is this a specific file the devs should have provided?  Or is it something I should download and add (somewhere/somehow)?  Sorry for being clueless..

Comment: Normally it would be creating when running a generator. In this case I think it is if you need customization. Did you do anything that might tell sidekiq that there should be a config file?